# Can I install Ubuntu 64-bit on Lenovo ThinkCentre M710t?

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit

I bought a Lenovo PC model ThinkCentre M710t.

It says The CPU is Pentium G4600.

Is it OK to install Ubuntu 17.10 amd64?

Comment: Yes, it's ok, in fact, very much desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is compatible with Ubuntu 17.10 amd64.
You have to create a USB drive installation media of Ubuntu 17.10 amd64 before installing. You could do that in Windows with a small application called Rufus. Rufus can be downloaded from [here on its official website](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

I strongly recommend installing Ubuntu in the UEFI & GPT mode.
Just enjoy Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

About your question, you can search for Hardware Compatibility in the [Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware website](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/).

For your specific brand Lenovo and model ThinkCentre M710, the official website recommends Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit version, here are more details of the search that I made for you:

- [Ubuntu on Lenovo ThinkCentre M710 with NVIDIA](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201611-25226/)
- [Ubuntu on Lenovo ThinkCentre M710](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201612-25267/)

Checking the hardware compatibility on this website before installing, gives you a very good advantage of wich features will be working or not without having surprises after the installation.

Hope this helps.